# Visual Studio / Xamarin.Forms Errors on New Project

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I was working on a Xamarin.Forms project for weeks - everything compiled and I was able to distribute. The last things which happened as of 05/20, were 1) a Windows 10 update occurred, and 2) I did a VS 2017 update.

Now the entire project has this "type or namespace 'system'..." error on everything. This is happening 1) upon creating a brand new project and 2) before doing anything - even compiling. Just opening the "App.xaml.cs" file after a few seconds highlights all these things in red in the IDE

A screenshot of partial list of the "App.xaml.cs" file and the errors is here:

[image: Errors on brand new project, no modifications]

### Other Info

I right-clicked solution and chose "restore nuget packages" - no change. I "cleaned" the solution - no change. I rebuilt... no change.

I am continuing to research and one clue which may help is that I can see the "NETStandard.Library" package in Nuget "installed" section shows "2.0.3" yet my common Xamarin.Forms project shows "2.0.1" and the drop-down of versions shows anything else is "blocked by project".

The other 3 projects, "Android", "iOS", and "UWP" will let me choose and install "2.0.3". I tried that once and then got a message about "mixed versions". At this point, I do believe the issue I'm seeing is related to this "NETStandard" package.

Cannot figure out how to make a brand new project load/use/install "2.0.3" instead of "2.0.1".

Answer (score 1):

I was actually able to install the 2.0.3 version by opening the nuget package console and installing the package to the individual projects one at a time using the command Install-Package NETStandard.Library -Version 2.0.3 -Project ...

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem like you and i solved this problem by add 2 package in package source.
In Visual Studio go to Tools -> NuGet Package Manager -> Package Manager Settings. Here select the Package Sources tab in the tree on the left. You should see the following: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4wSX.png)

---

- Name: `nuget.org`
- Source: `https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json`

---

- Name: `LiveReload`
- Source: `https://nugetized.blob.core.windows.net/Live-reload/index.json`

---